# MySQL Query: Which is Faster query

Tags: mysql

Method 1:

```
SELECT * FROM `wordpressusers` WHERE user_login='user10000001'
```

**Result from PhpMyadmin:**

[image]

Method2:

```
SELECT user_login FROM `wordpressusers` WHERE user_login='user10000001'
```

**Result from PhpMyadmin:**

[image]

What I think is method 2 is faster because it is selecting user_login column directly and MYSQL doesn't look to another columns. Correct me If i'm wrong.

I tried to query this in phpmyadmin and looking at the result, they are the same. I think this would make difference if the database is very big..

Comment: In order to benchmark that with phpMyAdmin you must skip Query Buffer in mysql. First SQL `SELECT 'A', * FROM `wordpressusers` WHERE user_login='user10000001';` Second SQL `SELECT 'B', * FROM ...` etc. Additionaly you may use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` in order to see what internally is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I expect #2 to be faster due to the reason already given.